# RequireJS module.config() always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am declaring a `require.config(...)` in an init script, then later requires some custom module and `module.config()` returns `undefined`.

For [example](http://jsfiddle.net/YanickRochon/L780gr6L/):

```
require.config({
   noGlobal: true
});

define('foo', function (require, exports, module) {
    $('#debug').append($('<div>', { 
        text : "Module config = " + JSON.stringify(module.config())
    }));

    return 'Hello';
});

require(['foo'], function (foo) {
    $('#debug').append($('<div>', { 
        text : "Got foo = " + JSON.stringify(foo)
    }));
});
```

How can I get the `require.config` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused by a misunderstanding of what `module.config()` does.

Included is a code sample to demonstrate.

**`module.config` demo**

```
require.config({
    noGlobal: true,
    config: {
        foo: {
            locale: 'fr-fr'
        }
    }
});

define('foo', function (require, exports, module) {

    console.log("Module config");
    console.log(module.config());

    $('#debug').append($('<div>', {
        text: "Module config = " + JSON.stringify(module.config())
    }));

    return 'Hello';
});

require(['foo'], function (foo) {
    $('#debug').append($('<div>', {
        text: "Got foo = " + JSON.stringify(foo)
    }));

});
```

**Solution #1 : Saving the RequireJS config in the `window` object**

```
window.requireJsConfig = {
    noGlobal: true,
    config: {
        foo: {
            locale: 'fr-fr'
        }
    }
};

require.config(window.requireJsConfig);

define('foo', function (require, exports, module) {
    // Access  window.requireJsConfig here    
    return 'Hello';
});
```

**Solution #2 : Saving the RequireJS config in the `require` object**

```
require.requireJsConfig = {
    noGlobal: true,
    config: {
        foo: {
            locale: 'fr-fr'
        }
    }
};

require.config(require.requireJsConfig);
```

Comment: Yes. I think this is an error in the `moment.js` [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/require-js/) and it should be fixed there.

Comment: Cross reference with repository [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1846).